# Can't mount image created with ddrescue (SFS partition)

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I am trying to recover data from a HDD.

For this purpose I am using Knoppix 8.1 on a DVD.

Running `sudo fdisk -l` gives me the following results for the specified HDD:

```
Gerät      Boot    Anfang       Ende   Sektoren  Größe Kn Typ
/dev/sda1              63       2047       1985 992,5K 42 SFS
/dev/sda2  *         2048     206847     204800   100M 42 SFS
/dev/sda3          206848  642795519  642588672 306,4G 42 SFS
/dev/sda4       642795520 1953523119 1310727600   625G 42 SFS
```

Knoppix mounts `/dev/sda3` which is the OS partition automatically. It cannot mount `/dev/sda4` however, which is where all the data is that I want to rescue. Mounting it manually won't work. It says:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on .....
```

With `ddrescue` I created images of sda3 and sda4 which wasn't really a problem. Mounting the image for sda4 doesn't work here either. I haven't found much about mounting a SFS partition. Is there any way do something about that? Next steps I am trying is flashing Knoppix on USB so I can install packages which might be useful for my usecase.